# How does Git deal with binary files?

Tags: git, binaryfiles

- Do I have to do something to tell Git whether some files are binary (like in Subversion)? Or, can Git handle binary data automatically?
- If I change the binary file, so that I have 100 binary revisions, will git just store all 100 versions individually in the repository?
- What are submodules for with git?

Answer (score 72, accepted):

1. Git can usually detect binary files automatically.
2. No, Git will attempt to store delta-based changesets [if it's less expensive to](https://web.archive.org/web/20180811051721/https://osdir.com/ml/git/2009-04/msg01221.html) (not always the case).
3. Submodules are used if you want to reference other Git repositories within your project.

Comment: Shouldn't this answer include a recommendation to _not_ use Git to store binaries? Git was explicitly designed for text storage, not binary. There are other tools which are better at archive management, i.e. NuGet, Maven, Artifactory, etc.

Comment: @skitheo I would've liked a more nuanced answer as well and particularly something about chance of things blowing up

Comment: @skitheo While you shouldn't version created binary files, there are binary files you do want versioned such as images, fonts, etc.

Comment: @DavidBradley, Yes, you can version control binaries used as source. If you do not keep it to the absolute minimum, you will regret it.

Comment: @skitheo Right or you'll end up with a very large repository to download if the large files change with any frequency. Git Large File system was created for this purpose.

Answer (score 32):

I had essentially the same problem: I wanted to git pickle files, which are binary, but git thinks they're text.

I found [this chapter on Git Attributes](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Attributes#Binary-Files) in the Pro Git Book. So I resolved my issues by creating a `.gitattributes` file with this line:

```
*.pickle binary
```

Answer (score 4):

```
git add my-binary-file
git commit
git push
```

Will add your binary file; it is automatic.

Indeed, if you have 100 versions of your file it will store it (but compressed).

You can use submodules to make references to other repositories.

Answer (score -6):

**The issue is with .gitignore**

The following paths are ignored by one of your .gitignore files:
XXX/YYYY/Bin1_0x1d_0x0d.bin

**Use -f if you really want to add them.**

git add -f XXX/YYYY/*

OR

git add -f XXX/YYYY/Bin1_0x1d_0x0d.bin